# istio authorization policy not being applied to istio gateway

Tags: authorization, istio, policy, istio-gateway

I have this gateway configured in GKE with a static regional IP.

```
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
  namespace: istio-ingress
spec:
  gatewayClassName: istio
  listeners:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: HTTP
      allowedRoutes:
        namespaces:
          from: All
  addresses:
    - value: "x.x.x.x"
      type: IPAddress
```

the service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-gateway-istio
  namespace: istio-ingress
  labels:
    gateway.istio.io/managed: istio.io-gateway-controller
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - appProtocol: tcp
      name: status-port
      port: 15021
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 15021
    - appProtocol: http
      name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    istio.io/gateway-name: my-gateway
  type: LoadBalancer
```

the HTTPRoute:

```
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: HTTPRoute
metadata:
  name: my-gateway-http-route
spec:
  parentRefs:
    - name:  my-gateway
      namespace: istio-ingress
  rules:
    - matches:
        - path:
            type: Exact
            value: "/test"
      backendRefs:
        - name: my-service
          port: 8080
```

and the authorization policy:

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: my-gateway-authorization-policy
  namespace: istio-ingress
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      istio.io/gateway-name: my-gateway
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
    - from:
        - source:
            ipBlocks:
              - x.x.x.x # Test IP
```

The policy is not working. I've gone through some troubleshooting, changing some configs, reinstalling everything and also trying to check the istio pod logs:

```
kubectl patch deployment my-gateway -n istio-ingress -p'{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"istio-proxy","args":["proxy", "sidecar", "--proxyLogLevel=debug"]}]}}}}'
```

but I wasn't able to find anything that would help me to solve this issue til now.

I'm using kubernetes gateway API:
https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/guides/

Answer (score 0):

The selector in the AuthorizationPolicy has to match the Gateway "workloads" as documented at https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/#AuthorizationPolicy

That means that the labels of the POD that hosts your Gateway config has to match that selector.
That means that if you want to apply your authorization policy at your Ingress Gateway the selector should contain sth like this

```
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      istio: ingressgateway
```

Answer (score 0):

As a part of the solution, restarting istiod worked for me.